# Getting AccessToken null in Facebook accountkit android device

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-access-token, account-kit

[Using this sample I am easily able to run and get access token](https://github.com/fbsamples/account-kit-samples-for-android)
but when I implement the same in own application its returning null value.

Comment: Could you provide the code you use to create the flow?

Answer (score 1):

Be ensure you have turned Enable Client Access Token Flow As shown in picture.

https://developers.facebook.com > Your App > Acountkit > Setting

[image]

Answer (score 1):

**Update:**

```
AccountKitConfiguration.AccountKitConfigurationBuilder configurationBuilder =
                new AccountKitConfiguration.AccountKitConfigurationBuilder(
                        LoginType.PHONE,
                        AccountKitActivity.ResponseType.TOKEN);
```

Please make sure that you are using **AccountKitActivity.ResponseType.TOKEN**

=============
Have you tried it:

> Access Tokens with Android 6.0 Auto-Backup
>
> Account Kit access tokens are not compatible with the auto backup feature introduced in Android 6.0, Marshmallow, because the backed up access token may no longer be valid. When your app used such an invalid token, it doesn't receive Facebook data in return. To prevent this problem, exclude the access token from the data that is automatically backed up.
>
> To do this, create an resource XML file in your project,for example, res/xml/backup_config.xml, with the following context.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<full-backup-content>
    <exclude domain="sharedpref" path="com.facebook.accountkit.AccessTokenManager.SharedPreferences.xml"/>
</full-backup-content>
```

Then reference the resource file in the `application' tag in your manifest.

```
<application ...  android:fullBackupContent="@xml/backup_config">
```

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/accountkit/accesstokens

Comment: Thank you, `AccountKitActivity.ResponseType.TOKEN` helped!